# OCI8 configuration with WAMP64

Tags: php, oracle, dll, wamp, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to connect Oracle 11gXE with php. For php I downloaded wamp64 which is a 64bit version and the Oracle 11gXE is also 64bit. I am using windows 10 also 64bit.

Now I never connected Oracle to php so after searching a lot I found OCI and PDO_OCI among which OCI is recommended.

Now following steps were mentioned everywhere.

- Download OCI thin client zip from oracle's official website.
- Extract the zip
- Include the path in environment variable.
- Enable extension = php_oci8_12c.dll (or what ever oracle version you have) in **php.ini**
- then use this `$con = oci_connect($username, $password, $connection_string);`

Now I have followed the steps, but failed to connect.
Following code to establish connection.

```
<?php
$username = "ABCD";
$password = "1234";
$connection_string = "localhost/XE";
$con = oci_connect($username, $password, $connection_string);
if(!$con) {
    echo "Faild to connect";
}
else {
    echo "Success";
}
?>
```

Now it show this error

[image]

So then I again I search to resolve this. Now I have faced following problems.

1. In my php.ini I didn't have php_oci8_11g.dll, I had php_oci8_12c.dl
2. And also had php_oci8_12c.dll in /ext.

So I downloaded php_oci8_11g.dll and mention **extension = php_oci8_11g.dll**.
Then try to run the code again but didn't work. Then in an article in here in stackoverflow I saw  32bit thin client is working because they had oracle 32bit and also xampp 32bit, But I have **Oracle 11gXE 64bit and wamp 64bit also**. So I have downloaded 64bit thin client.

Even I cannot see the php_oci8_11g in **php extension pane**.

[php extension pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGio8.png)
Please help me with this what to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to watch out for:

- You need to make sure you have the same 32 or 64 bit architecture for all of: PHP, the webserver, the Oracle client libraries, and (if you are using Instant Client) also the MS VS Redistributable.  (You did install the redistributable when you tried Instant Client? Check the Instant Client download page for details)
- The version of the Oracle client libraries you want PHP to use (either in the Oracle XE installation, or from Instant Client) must be in PATH (and before any other Oracle version).  Clashes between multiple version of libraries on Windows are hard to control. (Linux is easier...)
- The version of the Oracle client libraries should be equal to, or greater than, the Oracle client version that the extension was compiled with E.g. php_oci8_12c was compiled with Oracle client 12c (but which will allow it to connect to older and newer database versions) so Oracle 12.1 or 12.2 client libraries must be in PATH (before other Oracle versions)
- If you are downloading extensions from PECL, you need to make sure you get the thread safe, or non thread safe version of the DLL to match your PHP.  And it must be for the same version of PHP you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I have tried placeing the path in PATH variable and I have downloaded the libraries from Ocale website, and also have all things in 64bit vesrion. Any clue apart from all these?

Comment: You didn't mention that you'd installed the MS VS Redistributable required by Instant Client.